# How to deserialize Double brackets squarespace [[

Tags: c#

i am having problem when i will Deserialize json with C#.
the result is always null with my code this one.

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Root>>>(json);
            foreach (var item in result)
                foreach (var data in item)
                    foreach (Root jsoner in data.MyArray)
                        MessageBox.Show(jsoner.appId);
```

and the json I'm going to deserialize is this.

```
[
  [
    {
      "data": "test 1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "data": "test 2"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "data": "test 3"
    }
  ]
]
```

and this my class.

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Root2> MyArray { get; set; }
}
public class Root2
{
    public string data{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `[...]` is an array. An array can contain an array, object (`{...}`), or token (string, number, boolean, etc.). A "double bracket" is an array of array. So you really want `List<List<Root2>> MyArray`

Comment: The JSON has properties called `data`, but your classes don't. It's not clear how you're expecting this to work.

Comment: yes, I want to use it

Comment: Ah. I've edited it @jlrishe

Comment: Ok, so your `Root` class has a property named `MyArray` which is a list, but the JSON is nothing like that (it doesn't have any properties named `MyArray`). Seems like this would work if you simply did `DeserializeObject<List<List<Root2>>>(json)` instead.

Comment: I'm confused, if this is solved, why is there no answer?